# Marklogic computed bucket and UTC timeszone

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a computed buckets as follows

```
<computed-bucket name="older"  lt="-P1Y" anchor="start-of-year">Older</computed-bucket>
<computed-bucket lt="P1Y" ge="P0Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="thisyear">This Year</computed-bucket>
<computed-bucket lt="P1M" ge="P0M" anchor="start-of-month" name="thismonth">This Month</computed-bucket>
<computed-bucket lt="-P1D" ge="-P15D" anchor="start-of-day" name="twoweeks">Last 2 Weeks</computed-bucket>
<computed-bucket lt="P0D" ge="-P1D" anchor="start-of-day" name="yesterday">Yesterday</computed-bucket>
<computed-bucket lt="P1D" ge="P0D" anchor="start-of-day" name="today">Today</computed-bucket>
```

I have documents in my database with timezone specified as well in ISO format.. Will the buckets in ML calculated based on UTC ? if so can I force to calculate buckets in a different timezone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buckets will be based on the timezone of the host. If you can't configure the host to be in the desired timezone, you could calculate offsets and apply them to your anchors; however, I think the dynamic anchors (`start-of-day`, `start-of-month`, ...) are tied to the current time of the host.